Can 14th level Artificers attune / use sub-race specific magic items?
Relevant Feature Text
Magic Item Savant

You can attune to up to five magic items at once. You ignore all
class, race, spell and level requirements on attuning to or using a
magic item.

Scribe's Pen

Wondrous item, common (requires attunement by a creature with the Mark
of Scribing)

Keycharm

Wondrous item, common (requires attunement by a creature with the Mark
of Warding)

Finder's Goggles

Wondrous item, uncommon (requires attunement by a creature with the
Mark of Finding)


Question: Can a 14th level Artificer attune to these items?
In other words, I'm primarily asking if there is any proof that "race" clauses for the feature also carries over to "sub-race". Is there any text in any of the books that would imply / prove this? Or can Artificer's not able to attune to sub-race specific items they don't meet the criteria for?
EDIT: I was not aware of this, and I know it isn't RAW. But Jeremy Crawford said it would ignore such requirements.

In certain cases, the Dragonmark is a variant race.
In Eberron: Rising from the Last War the mechanics about Dragonmarks are the following (emphases mine):

Dragonmarks manifest on certain members of a few species, represented in the rules by variant race options:

For humans and half-orcs, a dragonmark is a variant race that replaces traits associated with those races.
For half-elves, a dragonmark is a variant race that lets you keep some half-elf traits and replace others with the traits associated with your mark.
For dwarves, elves, gnomes, and halflings, the dragonmark replaces your subrace.


Hence, for humans, half-orcs and half-elves Dragonmarks are explicitly a race: this can be ignored by the Magic Item Savant feature, per its description.
For the other races, Dragonmarks are replacing just the subraces. Indeed, as an example one can read:

So, if you’re making an elf character, you can choose to take the Mark of Shadow instead of being a wood elf or a high elf.

It is a DM call: they must decide how to treat the subraces case.
If I were the DM, I would ignore it as in the case of humans, half-orcs and half-elves, for being coherent among the various races.

The DM must decide how to treat it
For most dragonmark races, the Dragonmark is not a subrace, but a variant race (see this answer for details), so the question does not apply. For dwarves, elves, gnomes, and halflings, the dragonmark replaces the subrace, and the question does apply.
All that the rules have to say about the relationship between races and subraces is (p. 17 PH)

Some races have subraces. Members of a subrace have the traits of the parent race in addition to the traits specified for their subrace.

There is no explicit statement that the ability to ignore race also extends to the ability to ignore subrace. So, as this is not codified, your DM will have to decide.
For this decision, there are arguments for and against, in particular for dragonmarks:
The argument for ignoring it is that the dragonmark is mechanically expressed as a subrace, and subrace is part of race. Subraces are discussed in the PH under Races. And if you ignore racial restrictions, then that should ignore all race-related aspects.
The argument against is that if the artificer would just ignore all attunement restrictions, it would say so. But it does not allow, for example, ignoring alignment restrictions. And subraces are not races, they are more specific than that. Moreover, dragonmarks are not normal subraces, they are (p. 37, E:RftLW)

a symbol etched on the skin in colors more vivid than any tattoo, magical power made flesh

and merely are mechanically expressed as subraces.
I'd allow ignoring subrace, as Jeremy Crawford suggests in your quote, but I am not your DM, and neither is he (most likely:)), so check with your DM. Or, if you are the DM, decide for yourself.
